# Stop a kafka stream during a given period of time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm creating a kafka stream to replicate information from one application to another, the destination api has some maintenance windows when i don't have to send data or i can cause issues on it.

I have an api that gives me when there is a maintenance period this is not an issue, what i would like to know is how to disable the stream for a given period of time and start it again once the maintenance window is over.

I'm writing my code in Java

Answer (score 0):

you could manage kafka streams state like starting/stopping in a way that required to your use case. for that you need to have collection with your kafka streams in memory, and during maintenance stop them (either all or part of them) using
`kafkaStreams.close()` and `kafkaStreams.cleanUp()` on each required stream. when maintenance completed, start them by using `kafkaStreams.start()`.

Listening of mainetance could be done in a multiple ways, for example:

1. by scheduling (e.g. using `quartz` library). if you have multiple instances of the app, scheduler should be triggered on each node.
2. by some kafka topic like `maintenance_operations` (e.g. message with status `MAINTENANCE_STARTED` or `MAINTENANCE_COMPLETED`). your app always will listen this topic and start / stop required streams based on event. if you have multiple instances of the app, each node should have a unique consumer group for `maintenance_operations` topic.

Comment: Why would you call `cleanup()`?

Comment: to say the truth, I don't clearly remember why I invoked `cleanUp` during stopping Kafka Stream. maybe in order to just clean up local directory 'state.dir'